# Validating Associations with MongoMapper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongomapper

Models:

```
class User
  include MongoMapper::Document
  many :properties
  validates_associated :properties
  ...
end

class Property
  include MongoMapper::Document
  belongs_to :user
  many :services
  validates_associated :services
  ...
end

class Service
  include MongoMapper::Document
  belongs_to :property
  ...
end
```

In controller:

```
@property.save #returns false and true as expected
current_user.save #returns always true why?
```

It seems, that it doesnt validate the Property model with current_user.save method.
Why? :(

Comment: In my brief testing, `validates_associated` only works for embedded associations.  I'm investigating, because it's not immediately clear in the code why that is.

Answer (score 1):

In MongoMapper, assigning a non-embedded many association automatically saves the records you're associating.  But if any of those records are invalid, they silently aren't saved to the database. The next time you ask for the association MongoMapper goes to the database and finds nothing. The invalid records you assigned disappear.

```
user = User.new(:properties => [Property.new])
user.properties  # => []
user.valid?      # => true
```

You can use the `build` method to add objects to the association without saving.

```
user = User.new
user.properties.build
user.properties  # => [#<Property _id: BSON::ObjectId('...0e'), user_id: BSON::ObjectId('...0c')>]
user.valid?      # => false
```

I consider association saving to be one of MongoMapper's weak point.  However, it's not an easy problem.  See [issue #233 on github](https://github.com/jnunemaker/mongomapper/issues/233#issuecomment-1190404) for a discussion of the challenges.